# ordering cron of cloned feeds importer

Tags: feeds

I have two simple feed importers (one is the clone of the other, Feeds Admin UI and clicked clone under structure/feeds).

I would like to run both of them via cron.

if I go to

```
admin/structure/feeds/feed1/settings
```

and to `basic setting`, I can set `Periodic import` to every X hours.

Is there a way to set it that feed1 will run first every X hours, and feed2 will run right after feed1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you could try Feeds Ultimate Cron to achieve what you want: https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_ultimate_cron